# generate deserializer from xsd

Tags: c#, xml

I have a complex xsd
how can i generate deserializer for the an xml file.
using this xsd

Answer (score 1):

At the Visual Studio command-prompt:

```
xsd your.xsd /classes
```

which should generate `your.cs` with appropriate classes for a model that matches that schema. Note that it isn't 100% perfect - there are edge-cases that can confuse it.

Comment: but that class does not contain Deserialize method. i need to generate the Deserialize method some how

Comment: @user444569, the classes generated by `xsd.exe` can be serialized and **deserialized** to and from XML using the XmlSerializer class.

Comment: the xsd2code tool does generate everything, including a serialize and deserialize method.